# Kafka streams, custom key-specific time-window

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Given:
 Kafka-streams application that processes a high amount of messages (up to 500k/sec).
 The message keys are dynamic and highly distributed (financial data).

We now have a need to aggregate the data within time-windows.
However time-window definition could only be derived from a key. E.g.

- Key A -> TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofMinutes(1))
- Key B -> TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofMinutes(5))
- ...

Is there any plug-in point in Kafka-streams, where one can add custom windowing implementation?

Obviously, windowedBy function accepts only implementation of Windows or SessionWindows, which know nothing about the Key.

Comment: Sounds like you actual want a session window. Sessions can be based on the key, AFAIK

Comment: Unfortunately, session windows are only when there was no message during the configured interval. So if key A constantly has messages for 10 minutes, they will all appear in the same window. While I need them to be grupped within 1-min windows.

Comment: How many different windows do you need? Mabye you can just `branch()` the input stream based on the key and feed into different windows?

Comment: Also, it's possible to define own windows (not sure if the API is flexible enough for you use case though): https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/5.4.0-post/src/test/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/window/DailyTimeWindows.java

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Thanks for a suggestion regarding the branching. I also thought about such a workaround. However, my concern there is performance. With the branching approach, the aggregating application will end-up with ~1k windowing functions. 
Can you share some insights about the performance of such set-up?

E.g. if we configure num.stream.threads in such a branching set-up, will each of windowing functions be processed in the own thread-pool, or will they share a common one?

Comment: I would not call it a work around -- if you have a fixed number of window sizes, it's actually a quite sensible approach. Branching itself does not really impact performance (it a logical operation with not really an impact on the physical execution). Data parallelism is achieved based on partitions in Kafka Streams and branching does not affect it. Cf. https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/architecture.html#parallelism-model